# Although usage with the sentences without contrast meaning

Tags: grammar

> He is clever, but he is not proud.

My teacher ask me to change these two sentences into

> Although he is clever,he is not proud.

I think this sentence cannot be joined by using "although".In my point of view, the two sentences are not contrast. May I know your opinion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: The contrast is between "clever" and "not proud" in both examples. Why do you say "not contrast"?

Answer (score 1):

The contrast is given by the fact that being clever is usually considered to be worthy of being proud of. Even though your personal opinion on this subject is different (and mine as well, since being clever is - I think - mostly inherited), the context is given by the society one lives in.

In this context, the contrast is this: He is clever -> he could be proud of it / he is **not** proud.